# HazelCast client throws error when hazelcast server is restarted

Tags: grails, configuration, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast server and client. The client successfully connects to its server. But due to some problem when the server needs to restarts, the client is not able to connect to the server.
My configuration on client side is

```
<network>
    <cluster-members>
        <address>127.0.0.1</address>
    </cluster-members>
    <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
    <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
    <connection-timeout>100000</connection-timeout>
    <connection-attempt-limit>10</connection-attempt-limit>
    <connection-pool-size>30</connection-pool-size>
</network>
```

And the error I get in the client is

```
Hazelcast instance is not active!. Stacktrace follows:
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is no
t active!
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getClient(HazelcastClientPr
oxy.java:245)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getMap(HazelcastClientProxy
.java:95)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.getClusterMap(WebFilter.java:302)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.loadHazelcastSession(WebFilter.java:252)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.createNewSession(WebFilter.java:246)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.access$1100(WebFilter.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$RequestWrapper.getSession(WebFilter.java:
403)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$RequestWrapper.getSession(WebFilter.java:
314)
        at com.k12report.security.AuthController$_closure4.doCall(AuthController
.groovy:40)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(Pag
eFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter
.java:63)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:694)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$RequestWrapper$1.forward(WebFilter.java:3
42)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:704)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-07-10 21:22:18,929] - errors.GrailsExceptionResolver Unable to render erro
rs view: Hazelcast instance is not active!
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is no
t active!
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getClient(HazelcastClientPr
oxy.java:245)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getMap(HazelcastClientProxy
.java:95)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.getClusterMap(WebFilter.java:302)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.access$1000(WebFilter.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$HazelcastHttpSession.getAttribute(WebFilt
er.java:448)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(Pag
eFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter
.java:63)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:694)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$RequestWrapper$1.forward(WebFilter.java:3
42)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:704)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-07-10 21:22:19,130] - [/frontend].[grails] Servlet.service() for servlet g
rails threw exception
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is no
t active!
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getClient(HazelcastClientPr
oxy.java:245)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getMap(HazelcastClientProxy
.java:95)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.getClusterMap(WebFilter.java:302)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.access$1000(WebFilter.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$HazelcastHttpSession.getAttribute(WebFilt
er.java:448)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(Pag
eFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter
.java:63)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:694)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$RequestWrapper$1.forward(WebFilter.java:3
42)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:704)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-07-10 21:22:19,371] - [/frontend].[default] Servlet.service() for servlet
[default] in context with path [/frontend] threw exception [org.springframework.
web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: com.hazelcast.core
.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!] with ro
ot cause
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is no
t active!
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getClient(HazelcastClientPr
oxy.java:245)
        at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getMap(HazelcastClientProxy
.java:95)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.getClusterMap(WebFilter.java:302)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.access$1000(WebFilter.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$HazelcastHttpSession.getAttribute(WebFilt
er.java:448)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(Pag
eFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter
.java:63)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:694)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter$RequestWrapper$1.forward(WebFilter.java:3
42)
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:704)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And there is no any error on the server side.
Thanks

Comment: Which HZ version are you using. I looks like 3.1 or something.

Comment: I use hazelcast 2.3.2 jar.

Comment: I would advice upgrading to 2.6.9 http://hazelcast.org/download/

Comment: ohh.. Sorry I mean to say i am using hazelcast 3.2.3 jar. my bad :)

Comment: Also could you help me to enable logging in hazelcast client side. It would be a great help.

Comment: Which logging framework are you using?

Comment: Add the following to your startup:
-Dhazelcast.logging.type=log4j

Comment: Could you check hazelcast instance activity inside your app? If yes then write code with check and reconnection.